# Spring Boot Security Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, authentication

I am using spring boot security to handle login function. I don't know somehow the post method for login can't work at all. It will always throw the following exception.

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'POST' not supported
```

Can somebody suggest? Here is my code. You can find it from [GitHub](https://github.com/hanky91/SpringBootBlog/) as well.

SecurityConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll().and().csrf().disable();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

HomeController

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/login" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView login(Model model) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("auth/login");
        User user = new User();
        modelAndView.addObject(user);
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

login.html

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" th:action="@{login}" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Username</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" th:placeholder="Username"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" th:placeholder="Password"/>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                <i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-in"></i> Login
            </button>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div align="center" th:if="${param.error}">
        <p style="font-size: 20; color: #FF1C19;">Email or Password invalid, please verify</p>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Solved by updating config as show below. `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/", "/register").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and().csrf().disable()

    .formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard").usernameParameter("username")
    .passwordParameter("password").failureUrl("/login?error=true").permitAll().and().logout().permitAll();`

Comment: Im also facing the same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69450810/springboot-2-upgrade-login-is-not-working Can you please suggest what is wrong?

Comment: also where did you find out that the POST is called during login for authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Your Login function only accept GET requests. You should change GET to POST

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {
   @Autowired
   private UserService userService;

   @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/login" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public ModelAndView login(Model model) {
       ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("auth/login");
       User user = new User();
       modelAndView.addObject(user);
       return modelAndView;
   }
}
```

Comment: Nah, It didn't work. I remember the spring boot security takes over the post request for login method. But I just don't know how to configure it.

Comment: I edited my answer. I changed Controller to RestController. Please try this

Comment: thanks for your help. I tried but no luck. I read it from the [blog](https://medium.com/@gustavo.ponce.ch/spring-boot-spring-mvc-spring-security-mysql-a5d8545d837d) that the spring boot security will take over the post request, verify the user credentials and then redirect to another page. The post method in the controller is not needed, only need to change the configure file. But I don't know how to modify the configure file.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your Homecontroller login method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/login" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView login(Model model) {
```

or you could also use:

```
@PostMapping( value = { "/", "/login" })
```

Comment: I tried it before. It didn't work. I remember the Spring Boot Security takes over it and all verify user's credentials well.